# Assistance with the development of this formula

Tags: excel

I have yet another formula to develop further, i have the following formula

```
=IF(R9 = "NO", "YES","NA"
```

I need to expand this formula to do a similar thing to a previous question i asked. In that this formula looks in cell R9, if the R9 says no, then the answer in S9 should then say Yes. What i need this formula to do is the following:

If No in R9 then return Yes, If yes in R9 then return NA and if R9 is blank or has the symbol - then return the symbol -.

Iv heard you can do nested formulas but dont know if this would be applicable to this question or not.

Thanks again to all of you in advance for your help.

J

Comment: =IF(R9="NO","YES",IF(R9="YES","NA",IF(OR(R9="",R9="-"),"-","")))

Comment: Can you make this an answer so that i can mark it as the answer please. This solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=IF(R9="NO","YES",IF(R9="YES","NA",IF(OR(R9="",R9="-"),"-","")))`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(OR(R6="",R6="-"),"-",IF(R6="No","Yes",IF(R6="Yes","NA","")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try also `INDEX`/`MATCH`:

```
=INDEX({"-";"-";"Yes";"NA"},MATCH(A1&"",{"";"-";"No";"Yes"},0))
```

[image]